# Jenkins PowerShell Plugin parsing $env:BUILD_NUMBER

Tags: c#, powershell, jenkins, plugins, cakebuild

I am trying to use the PowerShell Plugin on Jenkins, to build my cake script. And i want to parse the `$env:BUILD_NUMBER` into the Cake script - and that is working fine in the PowerShell Window on Windows using:

```
.\build.ps1 -buildNumber=123
```

But when using the "same" *(Ok when parsing 123)* in the PowerShell Plugin on Jenkins - it Fails. It is not parsing the value of the `$env:BUILD_NUMBER` to Cake. I am using this:

```
$bn = $env:BUILD_NUMBER;
cd D:\_Builds\Al.Common.Std.Interface\SolutionItems\
write-host $bn              //Just at test writing 123 OK
.\build.ps1 -buildNumber=$bn
```

In the cake script i use the `$bn-value` as NuGet version Number. But i get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error : '1.0.0.$bn' is not a valid version string.
```

**Any ideas are very welcome**

Comment: Specifying a parameter with the equal sign doesn't work for me. Does the issue happen if you update the script to use `.\build.ps1 -buildNumber $bn` instead?

Comment: Cake doesn't seem to like that - getting: Running build script... More than one build script specified.

Comment: It sounds like the build number is being passed correctly now. If you can post the contents of `.\build.ps1` and we may be able to help you further.

Comment: That would be great 
https://github.com/cake-build/resources/blob/develop/build.ps1

Comment: The problem is solved using -- (2 minus signs) like: .\build.ps1 --buildNumber=$bn. Danm that took me days. You led me in that direction -Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to environment variables, probably the best solution is to just read them using the [EnvironmentVariable](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common/EnvironmentAliases/F508FA2B) alias provided out of the box with Cake.

```
var buildNumber = EnvironmentVariable("BUILD_NUMBER");
```

That said for acquiring the build number from Jenkins, Cake actually already provides a way of doing that out of the box using the [BuildSystem](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build/BuildSystem/) property alias which is globally available, it provides a [Jenkins](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build/BuildSystem/8040F127) property which wraps all kind of information about your Jenkins environment including [build number](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.Jenkins.Data/JenkinsBuildInfo/CF72FD83) as a typed integer.

```
Information("Running on Jenkins {0}, build number: {1}.",
    BuildSystem.Jenkins.IsRunningOnJenkins ? "Yes" : "No",
    BuildSystem.Jenkins.Environment.Build.BuildNumber
);
```

Above will output something like
`Running on Jenkins Yes, build number: 1.` if you're running on jenkins and `Running on Jenkins No, build number: 0.` if you aren't.

Now if you still want to pass as an argument to the issue is that PowerShell arguments work a bit differently than other shells and we've only wrapped the most common ones. For additional arguments to the `build.ps1` bootstrapper script using the ScriptArgs parameter like this:

```
.\build.ps1 -ScriptArgs "--buildNumber=""$env:BUILD_NUMBER"""
```

And then obtaining that parameter could look something like this

```
var buildNumber = Argument<int?>("buildNumber", 0);

Information("BuildNumber: {0} ({1})",
    buildNumber, buildNumber.HasValue);
```

And will output `BuildNumber: [NULL] (False)` if an invalid value is specified and something like `BuildNumber: 1 (True)` if a valid argument value is present *(and it'll default to 0 if no value is specified)*.